# jQuery UI tabs, the ID attribute

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

To demonstrate displaying an element containing tabs the [jQuery tab documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#overview) provides the example of:

```
$('#example').tabs();
```

I require multiple occurrences of tabs on my page so changed the example to:

```
$('.example', parentEl).tabs();
```

The parent element will only ever contain 1 occurrence of the tabs element, so this works as expected. However the content for each tab requires an ID attribute:

```
<div class="tabs">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#One" class="TabLink"><span>One</span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#Two" class="TabLink"><span>Two</span></a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="One"></div>
  <div id="Two"></div>
</div>
```

Since I will have multiple tabs (generated from a user event), I shouldn't really be using an ID?

Comment: Please be aware that [selector context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) uses [`find()`, internally](http://api.jquery.com/find). So it's slightly more efficient to use `$(parentEl).find('.example').tabs()`.

Comment: Will there be dynamic creation of both tabs and list-item/anchors to link to those tabs? Presumably there will be a 1:1 relationship between the `a` and `div` elements?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using an id.  This is how jquery knows exactly what content to load per tab.  If you leave the id off, however, it assigns a unique one to each element.

Comment: If I remove the ID attribute then not only do the tabs not work, I would also have to remove the href attribute of the tab, so how would jQuery now what content to display?

Comment: It appears you are right, for static tabs.  I was thinking of ajax-mode.  In this case, each tab gets a unique id assigned when first loaded.